# Django - Website runs on localhost, returns NoReverseMatch on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, django, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running a project online using Django, Gunicorn and Nginx. I am currently trying to update the website by adding new URL patterns and pages for the user to view.

However, this return a `NoReverseMatch` error whilst online, yet locally, Django doesn't return any errors. The error only occurs when the HTML file calls a namespace which I have added recently (i.e. this URL was not in the initial deployment of the website).

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'team' not found. 'team' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Though I have clearly specified this url and view function in the files.

Thanks!

**Edit:** I am using the namespace like so...
.html file:

```
<a href='{% url "team" %}'>team</a>
```

urls.py:

```
url_patterns = [
   ...
   url(r'/team/$', views.team, name='team'
   ...
]
```

views.py:

```
def team(request):
    return render(request, 'team.html', {})
```

Comment: care to elaborate more how are you using the name and namespace .

Comment: Did you reload application in Gunicorn?

Comment: @LeLouch Edited my question to include that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like namespace issue, Just clean the pyc files, this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16299786/6104063) can help you.

Comment: ?? You say *"Just"* do `x`. This is followed by a link that does not refer to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

this should work unless you have another namespace in your main urls.py for example

```
#main urls.py
url_patterns = [
   ...
   url(r'^club/', include('club.urls', namespace='club')),
   ...
]

#club urls.py
url_patterns = [
   ...
   url(r'/team/$', views.team, name='team'
   ...
]
```

in this case you'll have such error if you do that

```
<a href='{% url "team" %}'>team</a>
```

instead you'll have to do it this way

```
<a href='{% url "club:team" %}'>team</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use app_name when you want to render something like that:
app_name = 'team_list'

url_patterns = [
   ...
   url(r'/team/$', views.team, name='team'
   ...
]
then, in the a tag, try this: team